# Default NSDocument-based MacRuby application broken under XCode 4

Tags: xcode4, macruby

I'm using MacRuby 0.10 and XCode 4 where I have created a default NSDocument-based application. When building and running the app, however, no window shows, and the usual menu commands are largely disabled.

When creating a regular Cocoa-based application, the main app window shows just fine.

Does anyone have an idea what the fix is?

Dan;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Manually add a DocumentType to your target. Use a basic Objective-C project as an example.

Comment: This totally helped! Thanks! I just ended up copying the plist entry from a normal objective-c app.